# Update item's value defined using hatch before adding it to a list

Tags: netlogo

I would like to change value of an item before adding it to lists of a turtle's neighbours. 
I am setting the original value of the item's attribute inside the hatch. Then, I am adding it to the list of the turtle that I was considering. What I would like to to do now is to updated the original value adding a small quantity (perhaps random-float 0.1), in order to have attribute + random-float 0.1 for the neighbours' lists. 
The part of code that would be related to what I would like to change is:

```
to action

       if breed = breed1 [

          hatch-item 1 [
            hide-turtle
            set attribute random-float 1

            set this-item self
            ask myself [
              set my-list fput this-item my-list
           ]
       ]
              ask link-neighbors with [breed = breed1] [
              set attribute (attribute + random-float 0.1)
              set my-list fput this-item my-list
]
...
]
```

specifically these lines of code:

```
              ask link-neighbors with [breed = breed1] [
              set attribute (attribute + random-float 0.1)
              set my-list fput this-item my-list
]
```

What I am trying to do here is to change the value of this item, updating its original value, before adding it to the lists of turtle's neighbours. 
I tried to consider:

```
set attribute (attribute + random-float 0.1)
```

in order to update the attribute, but in the list the value of this-item's attribute is initialised again, so I have 0 + random-float 0.01.

Could you please tell me how to update the attribute value from the original (not creating a new value; *for example, if I have attribute's original value = 0.5 and random-float 1 is equal to 0.2, I should have a new value equals to 0.7*), then add it as this-item to the neighbour's list?

UPDATED:

This is an example of the current output:

```
(turtle 2) (item 16) with attribute 0.147
neigh: 0 (item 16) with attribute 0 with random-float 0.2
```

but what I would like to have is:

```
(turtle 2) (item 16) with attribute 0.147
neigh: 0 (item 16) with attribute 0.347 with random-float 0.2
```

I hope you can help me.

Thanks

Comment: What you say makes sense.  Can you share the version where you include the last "set attribute ( attribute + random-float 1)"  in the code, so that we can see the exact usage and context of that statement,  I'd like to inspect this-item before and after that statement.

Comment: printing the values before and after, I noticed that the value of the attribute is initialised when I call the ask link-neighbors. I updated the question, showing the outputs (current and expected), hopefully in any advice. Unfortunately I do not know how to change the code to let it work properly. I think the error is in the hatch, as there I am setting the value of the attribute. So myself add the item with the right attribute, but not the neighbours as they are outside the definition of the original attribute. But if I include the neighbours inside the hatch, the command does not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you testing the value, that code you have will change the value of the variable named attribute. So if you think it's not being changed, maybe you are asking the wrong turtle for the attribute value? You can see this by doing print statements before and after:

```
to action
  if breed = breed1 [
    hatch-item 1 [
      hide-turtle
      type "Old vlue: " print attribute
      set attribute random-float 1
      type "New value: " print attribute
      set this-item self
      ask myself [ set my-list fput this-item my-list ]
    ]
    ask link-neighbors with [breed = breed1] [
      set my-list fput this-item my-list
    ]
    ...
  ]
```

Comment: The problem is that I want just to change the original value of the attribute only when I add it to the neighbours' lists. I tried to use `ask link-neighbors[ set attribute (attribute + random-float 1) set my-list fput this-item my-list]` but when I print I get the new value of the attribute as `random-float 1`. What I would like it just slightly change the attribute's value, perhaps using `random-float 0.001` and not `random-float 1`. But the problem right now is that the value is not updating but creating a new one. Updated question with an example of the expected output.

Comment: checking the value of the attribute when I add it in the neighbours' lists is always 0, so something is not working when I set the attribute . The attribute is still initialising in ask link-neighbors  Thanks for your time.